# Passing an argument to Func<> in MVC helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda, delegates, func

I have <strike>stolen</strike> seen the following code from the interwebs. Method signarure is

```
public static MvcHtmlString RecordPager(this HtmlHelper html, PagingInfoModel pageInfo, Func<int,string> someUrl )
```

This gets called in the View as follows:

```
@Html.RecordPager(Model.PagingInfoModel, x => Url.Action("Index", new { page = x }) )
```

My question is **specifically about the last parameter**, i don't quite understand how can you pass the argument 
**x => Url.Action("Index", new { page = x })** into the parameter

```
Func<int,string> someUrl
```

I know this is an Extension method for MVC's HtmlHelper, etc. and Func<int, string> is a delegate expecting an **int** and returning a **string**, but where is the **int** in the argument x => Url.Action etc...

You may have gathered i don't understand lamba and linq and anonymous functions and all that modern jazz, but please provide a decent explanation for dummies like me who will encounter this same question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Func<int, string>` is basically a delegate with the following signature:

```
public delegate string Func(int I)
```

Prior to C# 2, The only way to pass a method to a  delegate (which is a pointer to a function) was to explicitly create a named method with the same signature as the delegate above, like the following:

```
public string MyAwsomeFunc(int I)
```

And that method could be passed to a method containing the delegate as a parameter:

```
public void SomeFunc(Func callback)
```

C# 2 introduced **Annonymous Methods**, which enabled us to create delegate handlers "on the fly", letting the compiler create the named method for us:

```
// Create a delegate. 
delegate string Func(int x);

// Instantiate the delegate using an anonymous method.
Func d = delegate(int k) { /* ... */ };
```

C# 3 introduced us to **Lamba Expressions**, which is the preferred way of handling delegates in C#. A lambda expression is an anonymous method that you can use to create a delegate. By using lambda expressions, you can write local functions that can be passed as arguments or returned as the value of function calls:

```
delegate int del(int i);

del myDelegate = x => x * x // lamba expression syntax
int j = myDelegate(5); //j = 25
```

What happened in your method is that it accepts a delegate type of `Func<int, string>`, and using the lamba expression syntax:

```
 x => Url.Action("Index", new { page = x }) )
```

x is the input parameter for Func, which is an int and is being assigned to the `page` property, and the Url.Action method returns a string, which is what the return type is expected to be. The compiler is doing the work of generating a delegate handler for us, so we dont have to. It would be the same as using the following approach with a named method:

```
string MyMethod(int I)
{
    string result = Url.Action("index", new { page = I });
    return result;
}
```

Then, sending MyMethod as a parameter:

```
@Html.RecordPager(Model.PagingIngModel, MyMethod(someInt));
```

**Edit**

Some reading material:

- [Eric Lippert - Annonymous Methods vs Lambda Expressions - Part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/01/10/lambda-expressions-vs-anonymous-methods-part-one.aspx)
  (Continue reading the rest of the series, there are five parts)
- [Annonymous Methods (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k.aspx)
- [Lambda Expressions (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

Comment: thank you for taking the time to explain this. I will be studying your answer :-)